# corePlot to insert time,date,month. for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I have to implement the scatter graph which have to contain the time, date, month, year acc to the segment clicked. The dta for this is to be getting from database of sqlite. Can anyone have it.

Thanks

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. What do you exactly mean by `Can anyone have it`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example apps included with Core Plot. The Plot Gallery and DatePlot examples both show how to plot date values.